# Can I use a single quote in a PowerShell 'string'?

Tags: powershell, escaping

I want to include an apostrophe in my string. Is it possible to do without using double quotes?

```
'This is a quote. Can`'t I just include a single quote in it?'
'This is another quote that doesn\'t work'
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
'Escape a single quote '' using a double single quote'
```

See the help for [the quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).

You can check out the help in the powershell command line by typing:

```
Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules
```

It explains that backticks are interpreted literally in single-quoted strings.

> Because the contents of single-quoted strings are interpreted literally, you cannot use the backtick character to force a literal character interpretation in a single-quoted string.

Comment: thanks for this. it seems sort of arbitrary that they chose to interpret `<single-quote><single-quote>` non-literally instead of interpreting `<backtick><singlequote>` non-literally.

Comment: Think of it this way: The only special character in a single-quoted string is a single-quote. It has to be because it delineates the string. By using a <backtick><singlequote>, you are adding a special character *combination*.

Comment: hm. It seems like <singlequote><singlequote> is also a combination.  I see the appeal of having one special character instead of two tho.