# escaping single quote sign in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a replace statement in my code whereby Band's is being replaced by Cig's. However when I put single quote it took the first sentence... Example 'Band'

I tried to use double quote but it does not work. Do you know how to escape the single quote sign?

```
-replace 'Band's', 'Cig's'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Escape characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) and [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx) from the built-in help (as pointed out by as Nacimota).

To include a `'` inside a single-quoted string, simply double it up as `''`. (Single-quote literals don't support any of the other escape characters.)

```
> "Band's Toothpaste" -replace 'Band''s', 'Cig''s'
```

Or, simply switch to double-quotes. (Double-quote literals are required when wishing to use interpolation or escape characters.)

```
> "Band's Toothpaste" -replace "Band's", "Cig's"
```

(Don't forget that `-replace` uses a *regular expression*)

Comment: Don't forget the inbuilt help system: [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Escape a single quote with two single quotes:

```
"Band's Toothpaste" -replace 'Band''s', 'Cig''s'
```

Also, this is a duplicate of
[Can I use a single quote in a Powershell 'string'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231410/can-i-use-a-single-quote-in-a-powershell-string)

Answer (score 3):

For trivial cases, you can use embedded escape characters.  For more complex cases, you can use here-strings.

```
$Find = [regex]::escape(@'
Band's
'@)

$Replace = @'
Cig's
'@

"Band's Toothpaste" -replace $Find,$Replace
```

Then put the literal text you want to search for and replace in the here-strings.

Normal quoting rules don't apply within the here-string @' - '@ delimiters, so you can put whatever kind of quotes you want, wherever you want them without needing any escape characters.

The [regex]::excape() on $Find will take care of doing the backslash escapes on any regex reserved characters that might be in the search pattern.