# Replace Single Quotes (') in Filenames

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I received a good suggestion in another thread to support the removal/replacement of specific characters from filenames in a directory structure.  Works as expected for common ascii characters (like `&`).

PowerShell (works fine to remove `&` character from filenames):

```
powershell.exe -c "Get-ChildItem 'c:\Media\Downloads' -Filter '*&*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '&','' }"
```

I also need remove single quotes from some files: Example: `mark's_file.txt`.

I've tried a few variants without success.  I think I am running into a punctuation issue I am unable sort out.  I also tried using a variable = char(39) and adding to the string.  No luck.

Any ideas to accomplish?

Note:  Would like a self contained batch file approach, vs calling an external .ps1 file.

Comment: Simply repeat it as `''` however don't forget your `-filter` only catches files with `&`

Comment: Success!  That's a variant I did not try :)  - thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a single quote in a Powershell 'string'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231410/can-i-use-a-single-quote-in-a-powershell-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Batch file also works fine to remove both `&` and `'` characters from filenames:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Remove "&" characters:
for /R "c:\Media\Downloads" %%a in ("*&*") do (
   set "fileName=%%~NXa"
   ren "%%a" "!filename:&=!"
)

rem Remove "'" characters:
for /R "c:\Media\Downloads" %%a in ("*'*") do (
   set "fileName=%%~NXa"
   ren "%%a" "!filename:'=!"
)
```

... but the Batch file start run *much faster* than the PS one!