# Escape single quotation mark character from R

Tags: r, regex

I have a function which calls windows powershell from within R. It takes a path, and returns the last time files in that directory were accessed.

```
folderInfo = function(path){
    system(
        command = paste0('powershell -command "gci \'', path, '\' -File | Select LastAccessTime'),
        intern = TRUE
    )
}
```

However, sometimes, `path` has a `'` quotation mark, which throws the function off.

```
folderInfo("c://folder with ' in its name")
```

I'm assuming I need something like this... but need help completing it

```
folderInfo = function(path){
    path = gsub("\'", "?????", path)
    system(
        command = paste0('powershell -command "gci \'', path, '\' -File | Select LastAccessTime'),
        intern = TRUE
    )
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You may try `path = gsub("'", "\\'", path, fixed=TRUE)`.

Comment: `shQuote("c://folder with ' in its name", type="cmd")` might work

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: [Can I use a single quote in a PowerShell 'string'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231410/can-i-use-a-single-quote-in-a-powershell-string)

I needed the single quotation mark inside the path name to be escaped from powershell, not escaped from R.

And it is just a idiosyncracy of powershell that you escape single quotation marks by a double-single-quotation mark.