# Rust Command Line Arguments

Tags: powershell, rust

I'm experimenting with command line arguments in Rust.

Windows Power Shell.

```
if let Some(a) = env::args().nth(1) {
  println!("parâmetro é {:?}", &a);
} else ...
```

ARG = "Qu'il" prints "parâmetro é Qu\'il" (ok)

ARG = Qu'il (results in apparent infinite loop)

ARG = Qu\il (idem)

So, what's the proper way to handle this (the error)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really discern what error you are referring to, so I'll explain the reasoning for the behavior you are seeing:

1. You are using the format specifier `{:?}` which makes Rust print the string in a debug-friendly manner. If you use `println!("parâmetro é {}", &a);` instead you'd see `parâmetro é Qu'il`
2. This is not an infinite loop. Apostrophes (') are special characters in PowerShell to define a literal string. The reason why nothing is happening is that PowerShell is waiting for you to write the rest of the string and finish with another apostrophe.
3. Like nr. 1

See more here:

- [About literal strings in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7)
- [Can I use a single quote in a PowerShell 'string'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231410/can-i-use-a-single-quote-in-a-powershell-string)

Comment: 1. {:?} Yes, I was trying to figure out what was that. 2. Ok, got it! So it's a feature of Power Shell and the "right way" to handle is just to double quote the string. There is no "exceptions" here. Right? Thank you.

Comment: @Gorducho If by "exceptions" you are talking about errors or bugs in your code or powershell, then yes everything seems to behave as you would expect.

Comment: Yes, got it! Thanks.